# custom method in nested, dynamic child component doesnt fire React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component inside my App that processes data from an API and uses it to dynamically create children (which are defined in their own components) based on one of the parameter values from the API call.  I am able to get the data through to render the components, but the onClick methods don't work.  Here's some code:
The parent Component(within the return):

```
  {this.state.customInputs.map((input, i) => {
                if(input.type === 'radio'){
                    return(
                        <div className="preference-section" key={i}>
                            <h2>{input.name}</h2>
                                <RadioCustomInput 
                                    radioActiveState={this.state.radioActiveState} 
                                    handleRadioClick={() => this.handleRadioClick()} 
                                    options={input.options} />
                        </div>
                    )
                } else if ( input.type === 'checkbox'){
                    return(
                        <div className="preference-section" key={i}>
                            <h2>{input.name}</h2>
                                <CheckboxCustomInput 
                                    selectedBoxes={this.state.selectedCheckboxes} 
                                    handleOnClick={() => this.handleCheckboxClick()} 
                                    options={input.options} />
                        </div>
                    )
                }


                })
            }
```

The children components:

```
class CheckboxCustomInput extends Component {

handleCheckboxOnClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let checkboxState = e.target.value;
    console.log(checkboxState);
    return this.props.handleCheckboxClick(checkboxState);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div className="preference-options">
            {this.props.options.map((item, i) => {
                return(
                <div key={i} className="checkbox-group">
                    <label 
                        className={this.props.selectedBoxes.includes(item) ? "active-box checkbox-label" : "checkbox-label"} 
                        htmlFor={item}>
                        <input 
                            className="checkbox-input" 
                            type="checkbox" 
                            value={item}
                            id={item + '_checkbox'}
                            onClick={() => this.handleCheckboxOnClick()} />
                        {item}
                    </label>
            </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
)
}
```

}

export default CheckboxCustomInput;

and the other:

```
class RadioCustomInput extends Component{

 handleRadioOnClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let radioState = e.target.value;
    let radioName = e.target.name;
    console.log(radioState);
    return this.props.handleRadioClick(radioState, radioName);
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="radio-group">
            {this.props.options.map((item, i) => {
                return(
                    <label 
                        className={this.props.radioActiveState === item ? "active-box radio-label" : "radio-label"} 
                        htmlFor={item + '-card'} key={i}>
                        <input 
                            className="radio-input" 
                            type="radio"
                            name={item} 
                            value={item} 
                            id={item + '_radio'}
                            onClick={() => this.handleRadioOnClick()} />
                        {item}
                    </label>
                )
            })}

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default RadioCustomInput;

Answer (score 1):

Is the radio working but the checkbox isn't? It looks like you're passing a prop called `handleOnClick` to your checkbox component, but expecting a `handleCheckboxClick` prop.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I saw that.  Now the check box works, along with the fix:
`onClick={(e) => this.handleCheckboxOnClick(e)}`
where I pass the event through.
Its starting to look like its more of a CSS issue, at least now with the checkboxes.  I had a simpler layout before, but was asked to make this a bit future proof, in case they make new elements via the API, since then, the checkbox isnt reachable unless I change  the input CSS from `visibility:hidden`
So still working with it.  Thanks again for your input.  Will post if I figure it out first

Comment: This CSS issue I was able to fix in the checkbox component by moving the `onClick` to the `<label/>` and change the local `handleChecboxOnClick()` to save the parameter like so: `let checkboxState = e.target.childNodes[0].value;`
Same fix works with radio.

Answer (score 1):

After editing the method prop invocation in the Checkbox component, I was able to pass the event through using the following tweak to my onClick method for each child: `onClick={(e) => this.handleCheckboxOnClick(e)}`

I also, as suggested by @larz, removed the function return in the parent and passe dthe method by reference only there.

The rest of my issue was CSS, in that the `<input/>` had a css rule of `visibility:hidden` and the `<label/>` element was handling the CSS visual interaction withthe onClick. To fix this, I moved the onClick method to the `<label/>` and added a native JS method to the chain for the property definitions within the child-local onClick methods, like so:
`let radioState = e.target.childNodes[0].value;`